# I can't run my Flutter/Firebase projects in Vscode

Tags: flutter, firebase

I can't run a Flutter/Firebase project on vscode. Whenever I try to run the application the program stops responding.

I followed these steps before running the application.

```
flutter pub add firebase_core
flutter pub add firebase_auth
flutter pub add cloud_firestore
flutter pub add provider
flutter pub add firebase_ui_auth
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
flutterfire configure
```

After getting the error I followed these steps

```
flutter clean .
flutter pub cache repair
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:bos_proje/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'; 
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  
 
String str = "";

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); 
  await Firebase.initializeApp( 
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
); 
var  db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
//Create a new user with a first and last name
final user = <String, dynamic>{
  "first": "Ada",
  "last": "Lovelace",
  "born": 1815
};

// Add a new document with a generated ID
db.collection("users").add(user).then((DocumentReference doc) =>
    str= 'Document ID: ${doc.id}');
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(str),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

EDİT:

I uninstalled Flutter and reinstalled it. The above error persists.
I get the following error

DEBUG CONSOLE:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
/C:/Users/gacwi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_web-2.11.4/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:152:43: Error: The getter 'winydowVar' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.
 - 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart' ('/C:/Users/gacwi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_web-2.11.4/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'winydowVar'.
        globalContext.delete('ff_trigger_$winydowVar'.toJS);
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.
```

After above error I changed firebase project. I got the following error.

TERMINAL WINDOW:

```
PS D:\flutter_projeler\denemeler\bos_proje> flutterfire configure
i Found 3 Firebase projects.
✔ Select a Firebase project to configure your Flutter application with · fir-test-75a53 (FireBaseTest)
✔ Which platforms should your configuration support (use arrow keys & space to select)? · android, ios, macos, web
i Firebase android app com.example.bos_proje is not registered on Firebase project fir-test-75a53.
i Registered a new Firebase android app on Firebase project fir-test-75a53.
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase apps:create android bos_proje (android) --package-name=com.example.bos_proje --json --project=fir-test-75a53
ERROR: Failed to create Android app for project fir-test-75a53. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write the main method as asynchronous, and you run a Flutter app, the asynchronous method waits for the Firebase connection. As a result, your UI will be paused. To avoid this problem, you can write it like this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  init();
}

void init() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
}
```

Comment: I did what you said. I keep getting the same error.